# what's the official release of @material-ui/lab?

Tags: material-ui

I installed  `material-ui/lab: 4.0.0-alpha.60`,
in my project, which is an alpha version that the `Material-UI` team doesn't recommend using in production projects.

I checked the versions [here](https://openbase.com/js/@material-ui/lab/versions), but I didn't find anything other than the alpha version.

What is the official release of `@material-ui/lab`, or what alternative I can use instead of it?

Comment: There are only alpha release. I'd be very surprised if MUI does in fact categorically recommend not using these components in production.

Comment: I think this explains why there are no non-alpha releases: https://material-ui.com/components/about-the-lab/